# Geoserver SLD styling with multiple filters & Denominator

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, filter, scale

I have a WFS Store - I add a new layer from there and style it.
Style is generating too long URL (Depending on a features requested). Often geoserver log is filled with.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP error code 414 for URL
Also this layer is on a heavy use, and server fails often due to thee memory usage.

So the question is, what would be a good way(s) to reduce memory usage?

Style is roughly like this;
Filtering 15 classes 3 times each, two different viewing scale and third for legend.
Does the amount of rules used heavily correlate on memory consume?

**FIXED 23.2-24
Sorry for late answer, I was able to make it work slighlty better by combining/dropping 1/3 off the filters, but thee ultimate fix was that the store I was using finally accepted a proper getcabablities.
Log still occasionally drop the same error but its stable.

```
<se:Rule>
    <se:MaxScaleDenominator>999999999</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>PROCESS</ogc:PropertyName>        
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>YEAR</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2020</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
            </ogc:And>
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>    
        </ogc:And>
    </ogc:Filter> 
    <se:VendorOption name="inclusion">mapOnly</se:VendorOption> 
</se:Rule>
```

```
<se:Rule>  
        <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
                <ogc:And>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>PROCESS</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>YEAR</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>2020</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                </ogc:And>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>STATE</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
            </ogc:And>
        </ogc:Filter>
      <se:MinScaleDenominator>100</se:MinScaleDenominator>
      <se:MaxScaleDenominator>20000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
      <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>Label 1<![CDATA[
                ]]>
                <ogc:Function name="strSubstringStart">
                    <ogc:PropertyName>YEAR</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Function name="parseInt"><ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                </ogc:Function>
            </se:Label>
            <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</se:VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="spaceAround">25</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="autoWrap">30</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0.1</VendorOption>
        </se:TextSymbolizer>
        <se:VendorOption name="inclusion">mapOnly</se:VendorOption> 
</se:Rule>
```

```
<se:Rule>
    <se:Name>Name 1, labe 1</se:Name>
         <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Name 1, label 1</se:Title>
        </se:Description>
    <se:MinScaleDenominator>999999999</se:MinScaleDenominator>
    <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>YEAR</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>8.95</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>YEAR</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>10.00</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
    </ogc:Filter>
</se:Rule>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - can you please clarify what you are trying to do, what is not working? which SLD rule is the problem and finally add the results of the log file (turned up to GeoTools Developer) when you make the map request

Comment: Edited question*

Comment: please add the results of the log file (turned up to GeoTools Developer) when you make the map request

Comment: and yes, many rules will require more meomory